# Compodoc incldue images within docs

Tags: angular, compodoc

This is an Angular project with compodoc to help document project.

In the compodoc > [demo](https://compodoc.app/guides/demo.html) they showed some examples of documents with images I was trying to replicate this within my project but could not make it work.

I have followed this [thread](https://github.com/compodoc/compodoc/issues/71) instructions.  To my understanding, the steps are as follows:

1. At the root of the project create a folder
2. Name the directory with `-a` flag: `-a screenshots` <-(Am I reading this right?)
3. When `npm run compodoc`. It should copy `-a screenshots` to `documentation/screenshots`

For me, it is not copying the asset folder into the `documentation` directory. Does anyone know how to make this work?  Compodoc's documentation does not talk about how to include images.

**Screen shot of my file structure:**
[image]

Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-a` is a flag and is shorthand for `--assetsFolder`.

1. Create a  folder e.g. 'screenshots' at the root of your project
2. Reference your image in markdown e.g. `![Screenshot-1](screenshots/homepage.png)`
3. Use `compodoc -p tsconfig.json -a screenshots -s` to run compodoc and copy your assets folder